Can't verify Namecheap domain on Mailgun
It's been 10 days since I set up Namecheap custom DNS for Mailgun, and nothing verifies except SPF. I've tried deleting and recreating the domain on Mailgun, changing DKIM length, and then found it was a Namecheap issue, where I couldn't find the CNAMEs using nslookup or dig. All I've found are people saying this is a problem with Namecheap that's unresolvable.

Mailgun instructions, and the values they give you, are incorrect for setup.
Anywhere you need your domain, you must either use @ or leave it out entirely. i.e.,
mail.mydomain.com => mail
krs._domainkey.mydomain.com => krs._domainkey
mydomain.com => @
I found this out by giving up and going to GoDaddy, where when you input the values Mailgun gives you, it lets you know how they'll resolve and ask if that's really what you meant.
